# Dependency Injection - declaring dependencies on sub-modules

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, module

How strict should I be on dependency injection using AngularJS? I am not sure what the general consensus on this is. But I have my main app module defined as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ionic',
    'ngCordova',
    'app.core',
    'app.hub'
]);
```

`app.core` does not depend on anything, but I have a service set up on `app.core` called `AppVersion`:

```
angular.module('app.core')
    .service('AppVersion', function () {
        this.version = '12.5.322b';
    });
```

One of my `controllers` in `app.hub` uses the `AppVersion` service:

```
angular.module('app.hub')
    .controller('InitController', ['$scope', 'AppVersion', function ($scope, AppVersion) {
        $scope.version = AppVersion.version;
    }]);
```

But the definition to `app.hub` has no dependencies declared:

```
angular.module('app.hub', []);
```

Should it? The reason I ask, is because the `app` module *does* have `app.core` declared as a dependency. So when the main `app` module is loaded, all sub-modules are beforehand. `app` depends on `app.hub` and `app.core`, so I have a guarantee that both modules are loaded when the main module loads.

AngularJS does not crash, and I receive no `console.log` messages. So it works, but I am wondering whether `app.hub` should be defined as follows:

```
angular.module('app.hub', [
    'app.core'
]);
```

Should EVERY module defined declare its direct dependencies, regardless of other modules dependencies? If so, why?

Comment: you don't need to declare the dependency in a sub module if it is declared in the main one. All module dependencies will be available throughout app. If you did declare it in `app.hub` and removed it from `app` would work the same. Really boils down to portability of modules ( as in use in other projects) as to where best place would be to declare the sub module dependencies

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing I should declare dependencies at the highest level possible? What's to say I should not declare ALL dependencies on `app`? It could grow long, but it ensures all dependencies are everywhere.

Comment: No real gain declaring at top other than whatever convenience you might prefer. All the modules get compiled first before any dependencies get called upon

Comment: Thanks man - now, if only I could accept this as the answer... ;)

Comment: @charlietfl Your comment sufficiently answers the question. Please post it again as an answer so that it can be accepted, upvoted and easily found by others who might need it?